# botón continuar y añadir con un mismo <FORM>

Tags: php, mysql, windows-forms, botón

hola a todos tengo una situación con mi sitio

tengo dos botones  uno es continuar que me manda a otro cuestionario y otro añadir que me guarda los datos del cuestionario que estoy contestando.

ustedes se preguntaran que por que no realizo la parte de guardar y continuar con el mismo botón y la cuestión es de que quiero con el botón añadir ir llenando una tabla que el usuario este mirando cuando llene el cuestionario este cuestionario puede contestarse infinidad de ocasiones por el mismo usuario hasta no dar continuar para pasar al otro cuestionario.

si me guarda la información pero el problema es que solo tengo un  para los dos botones submit y si precioso cualquiera de los dos, ambos me realizan la operación de añadir.cuando quiero que uno me añada y el otro me de continuar.

tengo lo siguiente.

```html
<div class="form-group">
                            <div class="btn-group btn-group-lg">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return continuar();">Continuar</button> 
                                <input type="hidden" name="metodoque" value="metodoque" /> 
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return continuar();">Añadir Riesgo</button> 
                                <input type="hidden" name="Anadirriesgo1" value="Anadirriesgo1" />
                                <input type="hidden" name="ID_proceso" value="<?php echo $_id; ?>">
                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Regresar" onclick="history.back(-1)" />
                         </div>
                       </div>
```

y en mi php tengo esto para guardar

```html
<?php
require_once 'conexion.php';
$_Anadir_Riesgo_que = stripslashes($_POST["Anadirriesgo1"]);
$_Metodo_que = stripslashes($_POST["metodoque"]);

if  (isset($_Anadir_Riesgo_que) == "Anadirriesgo1") 
        {
        $ID_Proceso = stripslashes($_POST["ID_proceso"]);
        $ID_QUE = stripslashes($_POST["ID_QUE"]);
        $_que = stripslashes($_POST["que"]);
        $_Riesgo = stripslashes($_POST["riesgo_que"]);
        $_criticidad = stripslashes($_POST["Criticidad"]);
        $_Ocurrencia = stripslashes($_POST["Ocurrencia"]);
        $_Reaccion = stripslashes($_POST["Reaccion"]);
        $_Valor = stripslashes($_POST[""]);
        $_Decision = stripslashes($_POST["Decision"]);
        $_Plan_Accion = stripslashes($_POST["Plan_Accion"]);
        $query = "INSERT INTO riesgo_metodo_que (Id_Proceso,Id_Metodo,que,Riesgo, Criticidad, Ocurrencia, Reaccion, Valor, Decision, Plan_Accion)
        VALUES ('$ID_Proceso', '$ID_QUE', '$_que', '$_Riesgo', '$_criticidad', '$_Ocurrencia', '$_Reaccion', '$_Valor', '$_Decision', '$_Plan_Accion'); ";
        $result = $conn->query($query);
        if (!$result) die($conn->error);
        header("Location: ../form_validation.php?var=$_Proceso"); 
        exit; 
        }
        elseif (isset($_Metodo_que) == "metodoque") {
            
        header("Location: ../form_validationtwo.php?var=$_Proceso"); 
        exit; 
}


?>
```

Comment: Tú pregunta está relacionada de algún modo con Windows Forms y/o C#? Si no es el caso, deberías quitar las etiquetas no relevantes.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es que el boton `Añadir` someta la forma a PHP y el otro solo llame una funcion en javascript, debes de cambiar tu PHP asi:

```
if  (isset($_Anadir_Riesgo_que) && $_Anadir_Riesgo_que == "Anadirriesgo1")
```

Luego cambia el otro boton eliminando el `submit` asi:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="return continuar();">Continuar</button>
```

Comment: el botón continuar si llama la función continuar en javascript, pero también me tiene que enviar a el otro cuestionario.